# How to fix legacy code that uses <string.h> unsafely?

Tags: c, windows, strings

We've got a bunch of legacy code, written in straight C (some of which is K&R!), which for many, many years has been compiled using Visual C 6.0 (circa 1998) on an XP machine. We realize this is unsustainable, and we're trying to move it to a modern compiler. Political issues have said that the most recent compiler allowed is VC++ 2005.

When compiling the project, there are many warnings about the unsafe string manipulation functions used (`sprintf()`, `strcpy()`, etc). Reviewing some of these places shows that the code is indeed unsafe; it does not check for buffer overflows. The compiler warning recommends that we move to using `sprintf_s()`, `strcpy_s()`, etc. However, these are Microsoft-created (and proprietary) functions and aren't available on (say) gcc (although we're primarily a Windows shop we do have some clients on various flavors of *NIX)

How ought we to proceed? I don't want to roll our own string libraries. I only want to go over the code once. I'd rather not switch to C++ if we can help it.

Comment: Unless you have run into problems resulting from use of the standard C library functions in the past, I wouldn't worry about changing your code base to use the safe versions. The additional cost may not be warranted.

Comment: I would recommend using the more standard `snprintf` when possible.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067728/are-there-any-free-implementations-of-strcpy-s-and-or-tr24731-1

Comment: Can only use VC++ 2005?!? Time to start looking for another job, I'd say :P

Comment: @RSahu Customers have reported crashes/inconsistent behavior due to overflowing the buffers

Comment: @glampert For new stuff we're using Visual Studio 2010 and soon moving to 2013.

Comment: @Basile `snprintf` is not available in VC 2005. Nor in 2010! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915672/snprintf-and-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Amazingly enough, there was a reason behind the VC++2005 mandate. At some point in the past, some customers had support contracts with us requiring that our software work on NT4. Those contracts have all expired but the mandate hadn't. Will work on getting that amended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First note that those "safe" functions are only marginally safer than the functions they replace. Most of those "safe" functions take an extra parameter informing it of the size of the destination buffer (which they use to check for overflows) and they check that no null pointers are passed where they shouldn't.
This can catch certain errors, but not all of them and you could make an error in passing the wrong buffer size.

If you don't want to switch to the secure functions, or you can't due to portability requirements, then I would advise the following path:

- Compile your code with Visual Studio with the deprecation warnings enabled
- For each string manipulation function that gets flagged, evaluate if there really is a possibility of a buffer overflow or null pointer being passed.
- Where potential problems lie, modify the surrounding code to ensure the error can't occur.
- When you are sure that all string handling functions are used in a secure way as much as possible, you add to your Visual Studio a define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to suppress the deprecation warnings.

As the code has been used successfully for a large number of years, I suspect that there are few places with problematic uses of the string functions.

Comment: Your last comment assumes "normal usage". Security bugs are often found when something is used the way it isn't normally.

Comment: @domen: No, that last paragraph assumes that if there was a security bug in the code, it would probably have come to light already or that there is no real interest from the bad guys to finding security bugs in the application.

Comment: That's not how it happens in reality. Heartbleed, shellshock, sandworm bugs were all years old, and all in software that's used every day by millions.

Comment: I give you that some issues don't surface for a very long time. But I don't see any indication in the cited examples that they could have been prevented by using the "safe" string functions or similar. Those attacks all seem to have exploited more fundamental problems in the affected software.